# Insertion sort algorithm flaw in Java code

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, insertion-sort

So I am going through some of the common sorting algorithms and have written this:

**Code**:

```
public void insertionSort() {
    int key; 
    int i;   
    for ( int j = 1; j < this.a.length; j++ ) {
        key = a[j];
        i = j;

        while ( i > 0 && a[i-1] > key ) {
            a[i] = a[i-1];
            i = i - 1;
        }
        a[i] = key;
    }
}
```

**Result**:

```
jan@janspc:~/Dropbox/programming/java/algorithms$ javac sort.java
jan@janspc:~/Dropbox/programming/java/algorithms$ java Test 
49, 68, 60, 14, 70, 8, 83, 96, 29, 7, 92, 35, 17, 84, 31, 62, 48, 95, 16, 22, 31, 97, 72, 55, 88, 63, 1, 63, 96, 32, 74, 15, 92, 77, 50, 13, 12, 36, 90, 93, 20, 15, 67, 88, 23, 31, 95, 90, 86, 65, 35, 27, 60, 4, 90, 11, 22, 97, 65, 88, 23, 1, 25, 21, 9, 81, 87, 56, 2, 4, 63, 52, 55, 86, 62, 30, 55, 64, 19, 10, 45, 92, 87, 43, 39, 95, 20, 43, 3, 30, 74, 64, 4, 90, 91, 93, 94, 44, 87, 21, 

49, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 15, 16, 17, 19, 20, 20, 21, 21, 22, 22, 23, 23, 25, 27, 29, 30, 30, 31, 31, 31, 32, 35, 35, 36, 39, 43, 43, 44, 45, 48, 50, 52, 55, 55, 55, 56, 60, 60, 62, 62, 63, 63, 63, 64, 64, 65, 65, 67, 68, 70, 72, 74, 74, 77, 81, 83, 84, 86, 86, 87, 87, 87, 88, 88, 88, 90, 90, 90, 90, 91, 92, 92, 92, 93, 93, 94, 95, 95, 95, 96, 96, 97, 97, 

Execution took: 110628 nano sek?
```

As you can see from testing, the first value is not affected by sort. What's wrong with my algorithm?

Comment: Note that in the first loop starting with `int j = 0` in an imprecision. Think about it..
Also, I would refactor 'j' to 'index' and 'i' to 'previous'

Comment: **EDIT:** The code in question above is fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first iteration, the while loop doesn't execute, because `i < 0`. In the next iteration, the while loop doesn't run because `i == 0`.

You should probably use `while (i >= 0 && a[i] > key)` (not tested though)

Answer (score 2):

You need `>=` here:

```
    while ( i >= 0 && a[i] > key ){
```

Without this change it never compares the following elements against the first one.

Answer (score 0):

`while ( i > 0 && a[i] > key ){` should be `while ( i >= 0 && a[i] > key ){`

Best luck...

Answer (score 0):

**Corrected code**:

```
public void insertionSort() {
    int key; 
    int i;   
    for ( int j = 1; j < this.a.length; j++ ) {
        key = a[j];
        i = j;

        while ( i > 0 && a[i-1] > key ) {
            a[i] = a[i-1];
            i = i - 1;
        }
        a[i] = key;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the pseudo code of Insertion sort(taken from CLR "Introduction to algorithms" book).

> Insertion-Sort(A)
>
> for (j=2 to A.length)
>
> ```
> key = A[j]> 
> i = j-1
> while i>0 && A[i]>key
>     A[i+1] = A[i]
>     i = i-1
> A[i+1] = key
> ```

Your code is almost similar to above pseudo code. All you need is to change initialization of `int j=0` to `int j=1` in `for` loop:

```
for ( int j = 1; j < this.a.length; j++ ) {
    key = a[j];
    i = j - 1;

    while ( i > 0 && a[i] > key ) {
        a[i + 1] = a[i];
        i = i - 1;
    }
    a[i+1] = key;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In [Insertion Sort](http://tutorialdata.com/example/Algorithm/InsertionSortExample.html) we need to check each and every element from array and compare with other element getting more accurate result. The problem in your code in while loop
we need line

```
while ( i >= 0 && a[i] > key )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another implementation of insertion sort in java

public class InsertionSort {

```
static int intArray[] = { 1000, 1, 100, 101, 15 };

public static void doSort() {
    for (int outer = 1; outer < intArray.length; outer++) {
        for(int inner=outer;inner>0; inner--){
            if(intArray[inner]<intArray[inner-1]){
                int temp=intArray[inner];
                intArray[inner]=intArray[inner-1];
                intArray[inner-1]=temp;
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void printArray() {
    for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("  " + intArray[i]);
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.print("Array Before Sorting->");
    printArray();
    doSort();
    System.out.print("\nArray After Sorting ->");
    printArray();
}
```

}

Detailed explanation of the code and/or the algortithm can be seen at - 
http://www.javabrahman.com/algorithms-in-java/insertion-sort-in-java/

Comment: Note that [link-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info), SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

here is a very easy implementation of insertion sort

```
package insertion_sort;

public class insertion_sort {
    public static void main(String ar[]) {
        int[] a = {24, 13, 9, 64, 7, 23, 34, 47, 87, 9, 37, 1992};
        insertion(a,12);
    }

    public static void insertion(int[] a, int n) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= n - 1; i++) {
            int value = a[i];
            int hole = i;
            while (hole > 0 && a[hole - 1] > value) {
                a[hole] = a[hole - 1];
                hole = hole - 1;    
            }
            a[hole] = value;
        }
        print(a);    
    }

    public static void print(int[] A) {    
        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {    
            System.out.print(A[i] + " ");    
        }    
        System.out.println();
    }    
}
```

Comment: That's not what the questioner asked for.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int[] insrtSort(int array[]){

    for(int i=0 ; i<array.length-1;i++){
        int value=array[i+1],k=i;

        while(value<array[k] ){

            array[k+1]=array[k];
            if(k!=0)
            k--;
            else
                array[0]=value;
        }
        if(k!=0)
        array[k+1]=value;
    }
    return array;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the same code but as a method that can be passed an array of ints to sort.

```
public static int[] insertionSort(int[] array) {
    int key; 
    int i;   


    for ( int j = 1; j < array.length; j++ ) {
        key = array[j];
        i = j;

        while ( i > 0 && array[i-1] < key ) {
            array[i] = array[i-1];
            i = i - 1;
        }
        array[i] = key;
    }
    return array;
}
```